# Short-circuit for If-else statement

Tags: javascript

So I know

```
variable && runTrue();
```

really means

```
if(variable){
    runTrue();
}
```

---

Then is there a more simplified way to write

```
if(variable){
    runTrue();
}else{
    runFalse();
}
```

instead of `if-else`?

Comment: Have you thought perhaps that you might want to write your code in such a way that people can actually _read_ it, without having to think too much?

Comment: To a sufficiently experienced coder, the most "simplified" code is the *easiest code to read.* If you want to make your JavaScript code more compact, then write readable code first, and then run it through a compressor ([Uglify](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) or something similar) as part of your deployment process. Win-win: you get to maintain code that you can read, but the end result is a smaller download for your users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I found out that this would do the same thing as a normal `if-else`:

```
(variable) && (runTrue(),1) || runFalse();
```

It is ***2*** characters shorter (still better than nothing) and tested in [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/if-else-vs-short-circuit-evaluation) that usually `Short-circut evaluation -  false` for most of time is faster than the normal way of doing this.

```
(variable) &&           //If variable is true, then execute runTrue and return 1
(runTrue(),1) ||        // (so that it wouldn't execute runFalse)
runFalse();             //If variable is false, then runFalse will be executed.
```

But of course, you can always use `variable?runTrue():runFalse();`.

Comment: -1.  Two characters is *not* a big gain. "Maybe" being faster is *not* a plus.  Making the simplest construct totally cryptic is a big minus.

Comment: -1. The appropriate shortcut is a ternary expression: `variable? runTrue() : runFalse();`

Comment: @Derek—"it works" is not sufficient justification to prefer it over an alternative when the criterion was `a more simplified way`, not less code.

Comment: @squint—there is no way to pass the "calling context" to the function since you are explicitly barred from accessing it by ECMA–262. You can set the called function's *this* keyword though, but the OP doesn't do that or request it. And anyway, it's **more** code that the `?:` operator.

Answer (score 7):

Ternary expressions using the [conditional operator](http://es5.github.com/#x11.12) `? :` were invented for such simple binary choices:

```
function a() {alert('odd')}
function b() {alert('even')}
var foo = new Date() % 2;

foo? a() : b(); // odd or even, more or less randomly
```

is equivalent to:

```
if (foo % 2) {
  a(); // foo is odd
} else {
  b(); // foo is even
}
```